# Assert data type of the values of a dict when they are in a list

Tags: python

How can I assert the values of my dict when they are in a list

```
My_dict = {'chr7': [127479365, 127480532], 'chr8': [127474697, 127475864], 'chr9': [127480532, 127481699]}
```

The code to assert this

```
assert all(isinstance(values, int) for values in My_dict.values()),"The values of the dict are not interger"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually want to check values of your dict are lists and that all of their elements are integers.

```py
assert all(
    isinstance(value, list) and all(isinstance(el, int) for el in value)
    for value in data_loaded.values()
), "Values of the dictionnary aren't lists of integers"
```

Comment: Great ! Consider accepting my answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

For nested iterables you need nested iteration:

```
assert all(isinstance(i, int) for l in My_dict.values() for i in l)
```