# How to iterate over the elements in lists in the values of a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to assert if all values in lists in the values of a dict are integer.

My dictionary is very long and I don't know an efficient way to do this.

My dictionary looks like this:

```
{'chr7': [[127471196, 127472363], [127472363, 127473530], [127473530, 127474697], [127474697, 127475864], [127475864, 127477031], [127477031, 127478198], [127478198, 127479365], [127479365, 127480532]], 'chr8': [[127480532, 127481699], [127471196, 127472363], [127472363, 127473530], [127473530, 127474697], [127474697, 127475864]], 'chr9': [[127475864, 127477031], [127477031, 127478198], [127478198, 127479365], [127479365, 127480532], [127480532, 127481699]], 'chrX': [[127480532, 127481699]], 'chr1': [[127471196, 127472363], [127472363, 127473530], [127473530, 127474697], [127474697, 127475864], [127475864, 127477031], [127477031, 127478198], [127478198, 127479365], [127479365, 127480532]], 'chr2': [[127480532, 127481699], [127471196, 127472363], [127472363, 127473530], [127473530, 127474697], [127474697, 127475864]], 'chr3': [[127475864, 127477031], [127477031, 127478198]], 'chr4': [[127478198, 127479365], [127479365, 127480532], [127480532, 127481699]], 'chrY': [[127480532, 127481699]]}
```

I have been trying something like this

```
assert all(isinstance(value, list) and all(isinstance(el, int) 
        for el in value)for value in bed_data.values()), "Values of the dictionnary aren't lists of integers"
```

(Code copy from here [Assert data type of the values of a dict when they are in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69373583/assert-data-type-of-the-values-of-a-dict-when-they-are-in-a-list))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generator:

```
assert all(isinstance(e, int)
           for l1 in bed_data.values()
           for l2 in l1 for e in l2)
```

It will raise an AssertionError for the first invalid value. If all values are correct, there is no choice but to test them all.

Comment: this will check the int values inside a iterator, which work fines. but if Op wants to check iterator also then this need to be modified to that

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to try all items. Stop at the first failed test (not an instance of `int`) and prefer use `TypeError` rather than `AssertionError`:

```
import itertools

for l in bed_data.values():
    for v in itertools.chain.from_iterable(l):
        if not isinstance(v, int):
            raise TypeError(f"Values of the dictionnary aren't lists of integers '{v}'")
```

Comment: When you're working with a so-small datas there won't be problem with using the other method. The problem is when you're using a two-for-loops generator with for example a 1000 values lenght dictionary, then there will be trouble.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO. Especially in the worst case where the first value is not an integer!

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO how is this more efficient? NB. I timed both answer on 4M items (all int 1000*200*20) mine runs at `162 ms ± 2.21 ms` and this one `215 ms ± 5.13 ms`. For an early failing value, there is no real difference

Comment: @mozway, I tought there should have been a real difference for an early failing value. Since you said it's not true, probably your answer is faster. Then, as I said before, since the OP has a very short dictionary, there wouldn't be problem even if the method was really unefficient.